# Bash script does not catch sbt command return error

Tags: bash, sbt

In our bash script, we run `sbt` command. I want to catch an error in case `sbt` failed, but cannot figure out how to do it. I've tried the following two approaches after googling around:

Approach 1:

```
sbt ${assemblyCmd} |tee ${TARGET}/assembly.log 
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ];
then echo "Build jar successfully"
else
    echo "Failed to build jar"
    exit 1
fi
```

Approach 2

```
if sbt ${assemblyCmd} |tee ${TARGET}/assembly.log
then echo "Build jar successfully"
else
    echo "Failed to build jar"
    exit 1
fi
```

Neither of them work. I can see `sbt` failed with an error message but bash still outputs `Build jar successfully`:

```
[0m[[0m[0minfo[0m] [0m[0mCompiling 21 Scala sources to /opt/utility/spark-jobs/target/scala-2.10/classes ...[0m
[0m[[0m[31merror[0m] [0m[0m/opt/utility/spark-jobs/src/main/scala/com/st/spark/jobs/SubAudit.scala:130:3: type mismatch;[0m
[0m[[0m[31merror[0m] [0m[0m found   : Unit[0m
[0m[[0m[31merror[0m] [0m[0m required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame[0m
[0m[[0m[31merror[0m] [0m[0m  }[0m
[0m[[0m[31merror[0m] [0m[0m  ^[0m
[0m[[0m[31merror[0m] [0m[0mone error found[0m
[0m[[0m[31merror[0m] [0m[0m(SparkJobs / Compile / [31mcompileIncremental[0m) Compilation failed[0m
[0m[[0m[31merror[0m] [0m[0mTotal time: 16 s, completed Apr 11, 2019 5:28:26 PM[0m
Build jar successfully
```

`sbt` failed at compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider writing your log messages to standard error instead of standard output. Then you can pipe the output of the entire `if` statement to `tee`, instead of just the `sbt` command.

```
# You should *probably* quote $assemblyCmd, but there's not
# enough context to know if you are relying on word-splitting.
if sbt $assemblyCmd; then
  echo "Build jar successfully" >&2
else
  echo "Failed to build jar" >&2
  exit 1
fi | tee "$TARGET"/assembly.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You always get a success exit code, because the tee command always succeeds. sbt is the command which returns a non-zero exit code. You can make use of the $PIPESTATUS variable for this case, which can be used to check the status of multiple piped commands.

```
sbt ${assemblyCmd} |tee ${TARGET}/assembly.log

if [ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" -eq 0 ];
    then echo "Build jar successfully"
else
    echo "Failed to build jar"
    exit 1
fi
```